# What is, in layman terms, a Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am aware question is highly correlated with [What is the significance of a Borel $\sigma$-algebra?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092704/what-is-the-significance-of-a-borel-sigma-algebra)
However, I am looking for a high-level explanation about Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Probabilities can be explained very intuitively to an average person, I am wondering whether also this concept can be demystified without using too much mathematical jargon.

Comment: This is very vague.  What's wrong with the standard definition, as given, say, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra)?  I think that any "high level"  discussion of the notion is going to essentiually restate the definition.

Comment: I think of the Borel $\sigma$-field as the largest most "down to Earth" set where one can define length, area, volumen, etc. In other words, it easily follows that $\mathfrak{P}_\mathbf{R}$ cannot have an additive measure and one can say that it is mathematically useful to let limits in and out of the measure (I learned it like this when I was 19 and I found it acceptably intuitive), thus the Borel $\sigma$-algebra would be the largest $\sigma$-field where the Lebesgue measure behaves well (this is actually not true but for intuition is quite fine). You can later show this is up to nullity.

Comment: I don't think $\sigma$-algebras can be defined in layman's terms (e.g. count the number of mathematical terms each of the answers below uses). Best I can do is "the sets for which I can define a probability, where the sets are chosen to reasonably interact with the notion of length". This should sound like absolute nonsense to a layman.

Comment: I understand your point of view. In my opinion, "closed under complement, and is closed under countable unions" are non-intuitive properties or, at least, it is hard to understand why they are necessary for the probability context

Comment: @pentavol If $A$ and $B$ are events, $A\cup B$ is the event that either $A$ or $B$ occur, $A\cap B$ is the event that they both occur, and $A^c$ is the event that $A$ does not occur. (This doesn't explain why countable-but not necessarily uncountable-unions and intersections are what we want but does explain why we should at least want our collection of events to have closure under elementary set operations. i.e. why they should at least form an algebra.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen - Thanks for the explanations, it makes more sense now. What makes Borel sigma-algebra more special than sigma-algebra? Why isn't any sigma-algebra enough for the probability context?

Comment: @pentavol General sigma algebras do come up in probability theory... a probability space consists of a set $\Omega,$ a sigma algebra $\Sigma$ on $\Omega$ of measurable sets (i.e. the events) and a probability measure defined on that sigma algebra. Where the Borel sigma algebra comes up specifically is in the definition of real-valued random variables, which implies for a random variable $X$ and Borel set $B\subseteq \mathbb R$, the probability $P(X\in B)$ is well-defined. The reason for Borel there is we want the probability of a random variable falling in some interval to be well-defined.

Answer (score 0):

A Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$ is any subset that can be obtained by starting with open sets and applying the operations of union of finite or infinite sequence of set and of complementation of sets. Thus if $A,B,C$ are Borel sets then $A\cup B\cup C$ is a Borel set, and if $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots$ is an infinite sequence of Borel sets then $A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup\cdots$ is a Borel set.

By de Morgan's laws we have
\begin{align}
& A_1 \cap A_2\cap A_3\cap \cdots \\[8pt]
= {} & \mathbb R\smallsetminus\big((\mathbb R \smallsetminus A_1) \cup(\mathbb R\smallsetminus A_2) \cup(\mathbb R\smallsetminus A_3) \cup\cdots\big)
\end{align}
and so the intersection is also a Borel set.

Although the class of Borel sets is closed under the operations of union and intersection of infinite **sequences** of sets, it is not closed under arbitrary unions or arbitrary interesections. For example, the set of all open sets that contain $0$ as a member has an intersection (namely the singleton set $\{0\}$) but this operation of taking the intersection of a set of sets is not an instance of taking the intersection of a **sequence** of sets. (Nonetheless, the singleton set $\{0\}$ is a Borel set, since it is the complement of the **open** set $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,+\infty).$

Thus:

- Start with open sets.
- Close under the operations complementation of sets and of union of (finite or infinite) sequences of sets, and consequently (by de Morgan) also under the operation of intersection of sequences of sets.

What you get is Borel sets.

A probability distribution assigns a probability to every Borel subset of $\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

I am not really an expert, not sure that will be able to explain coherently.

On a technical level, attributing a probability to any subset can be shown to be not realistic. This is somewhat technical - there are more subsets than subsets that can be reasonably described ("non-measurable subsets"). In some sense, one can show that there are subsets for which there is no description - this is something about axiomatics of mathematics. So one describes a huge collection of subsets of, say, $[0,1]$, which is closed under reasonable operations, and you would like to only ask about the probability of falling into such subsets (the collection is the $\sigma$-algebra).

But I think that there is also a less technical facet, more probability-related. It might be that you started with a system, and then consider experiments of some more restricted sort, and those experiments can never distinguish between two events $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$. Then you would like, to adjust to this new reality, to have all your "legitimate" subsets of events to either contain both $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ or not contain neither. So you come up with the idea of a $\sigma$-algebra adjusted to this new reality, of a person with glasses of worse quality (so you can look up something like "tail $\sigma$-algebra" or something like this... not really an expert...)

Answer (score 0):

It is better to correlate this with lebesgue measure.
Rieman integral fails coz it cannot break down the input after 3 dimensions. For 1d it’s rectangles...for 2d it’s cubes etc what about 4d?

By shifting domain from x to y we end up with dividing the different function outputs into slices and then multiplying them by input measure. This becomes a measure problem and assigning a measure has to obey some conditions.

Like for examples areas should be additive. Skipping over much detail here. If you use power set as sigma algebra then some of these basic conditions are not satisfied. Now if you read standard definition of sigma algebra it will make more sense. It’s just a way of assigning measure for use in lebesge integration

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give my personal perspective on Borel–$\sigma$ algebras. Hopefully, it will be useful for both of us.

If we consider the Riemann integral, there are some natural questions we can ask. Suppose that $f_n$ are a sequence of continuous functions, for simplicity on $[0,1]$. We know that $f_n$ are integrable because they are continuous. Furthermore, let us suppose that $f_n \rightarrow f$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Now what can we say about the (Riemann) integrability of $f$ and what is $\int f$?

*I will spoil the answers to these questions and say that we can not deduce anything about $f$, because we can find a sequence of bounded continuous functions which converge to a non–integrable (non Riemann integrable) function*

That is besides the point. Let us pretend that we didn't know the answer above and try to investigate possible answers to the questions I raised earlier. Naturally, we need to understand what kind of function $f$ is before we attempt to address what $\int f$ is or even whether it is integrable.

Well, it turns out it is a Borel function. Meaning, $f^{-1}(A)$ is a Borel set for a Borel set $A  \subset \mathbb{R}$. To see why, notice that if $x \in f^{-1}((a,\infty)) $ then for some large $N_x$, we get for all $n\ge N_x$ that $x\in f^{-1}_{n}((a,\infty))$. So after some thinking, we would deduce that $$f^{-1}(a,\infty) = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap_{m=n}^{\infty}f_m^{-1}(a,\infty)$$

Since, $f_m^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is open set for all $m$, in order to understand $f$, we need to understand what happens when we take countable intersection of open sets. I am too tired to write about why complement is important but a similar heuristic can be provided. Maybe I will do that tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Basically, a $\sigma$-algebra is a subset of all the possible sets X on space and allow's us to define a measure. Basically, how large is each subset of X provided it is in the $\sigma$-algebra. A Borel $\sigma$-algebra is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains all the open, closed, half-way open, half-way closed, and ray sets within a space. Consider, R. A Borel $\sigma$-algebra will have all the $(a,b), [a,b], (a,b], [a,b), (-\infty,a),(-\infty,a]$. At the high level, we can figure out how large each of the above sets is on a measure.

Answer (score -1):

Say you have something random that produces a real number.

Say I can tell you the probability the number is greater than a, less than b, in between a and b inclusive etc. That seems pretty reasonable because saying the quantity is in between two numbers is useful for constraining it. Those are the nicer sets to work with.

Suppose also if I can tell you the probability for $X$ and $Y$, then I also can do $X \bigcup Y$ and $X \bigcap Y$ and $X \setminus Y$. Same if there are more than just 2 to take unions and intersections.

For example, if I know the probability for being between 2 and 3 is .1 and the probability for being above 6 is .001, then I can immediately say .101 for the union because it has to be exactly one of those two events because it is a disjoint union.

But even with all these sets I can tell you probabilities for, there are still lots of sets I cannot because they aren't built up from intervals. Intervals were my starting point of understanding this random number.